# Android google API (JAVA), How to create folder and its sub folder at a same time?

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have a code to create a folder but don't getting an idea to create a sub folder inside the folder.Please Advise!

```
 private void createFolderInDrive() throws IOException {
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("Test1 Folder");
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

        File file = mService.files().create(fileMetadata)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());

        Log.e(this.toString(),"Folder Created with ID:"+ file.getId());

        createSubFolderInDrive(file.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Folder created:"+file.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create local folder or Google Drive folder?

Answer (score 0):

to create directory within a directory use [File.mkdirs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()), like:

```
new File("/myDirectory/mySubdirectory").mkdirs();
```